# Jon can jump off badges. Is that metaphorically intended?

Tags: discussion, unikong

Not really evident from the picture but if timed correctly, Jon can jump in mid air from a badge. Apart from being very nice, is that by-design?

[image]

Comment: Jon skeet should get paid in swag for this.  Gold covered SO t-shirts...

Comment: Tempted to downvote for daring to suggest something I "shouldn't" be able to do ;)

Comment: _Jon can jump in mid air from a badge._ Oh yes. And, if he himself is playing, then he can ride the unicorn too. Can't you @JonSkeet ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it is part of the design. We think it's funny, and neat.

As for the metaphor part of your question: sure, why not.

Comment: You guys rock.!